# Part Part Whole

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sam had cookies for his party. He gave all $20$ of his guests a cookie. His granny brought $24$ more cookies. Sam put aside $4$ cookies. If Sam has $16$ cookies now, what did he begin with?

Answer (score 2):

$x:$ how many cookies Sam started with.

$$x -20 + 24 - 4 = 16$$

Solve for $x$.

$$x = 16 + 20 -24 + 4 = 16$$

(assuming there are an additional $4$ cookies Sam set aside, perhaps to give to  his girl-friend!)

Comment: Give me all the cookies. :-p